# Riemann integral formula

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

my professor gave us this formula--but I was curious--how it is derived? Where does it come from?
$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)=\frac{b-a}{n}[f(b)-f(a)]$$

I found it useful by plugging in that
$$U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)=\frac{\ln2}{n}$$ for a function $\ln x$ from $1$ to $2$,  $\forall n\geq1$. I just don't see how to derive it--so that I can memorize it. We were just told it was "useful". FYI I know the definitions of upper and lower sums, how to calculate the Riemann integral etc.

Comment: Isn't the upper sum defined by taking the maximum value on each subinterval (and lower sum from the minimum)?  If so, then unless the function is monotone, the claim isn't true...take $f(x)=1-x^2$ on $[-1,1]$.  with $n=2$.  Surely the upper sum is $2$ (as the max for $f(x)$ on both subintervals is $1$) but the lower sum is $0$.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant the interval from 1 to 2

Comment: There is the proof: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration)

Comment: As I say, the claim is false for general functions.  True if the function is monotone.

Comment: The formula is wrong except in some specific conditions, as lulu commented before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for a monotone increasing function.
The (b-a)/n factor is $\Delta x$.
$U(f,P_n)$ is the sum of the values on the right-hand side of each interval.
$L(f,P_n)$ is the sum of the values on the left-hand side of each interval.
The right-hand side of one interval is the left-hand side of the next one.  So when you subtract one sum from the other, most of the terms cancel, leaving just f(b) from $U(f,P_n)$ and f(a) from $L(f,P_n)$
It also works for monotone decreasing functions.